# Celebrating Jesus' ministry after 2,000 years?

Tags: life-of-jesus, denomination-survey, celebrations

**Celebrating Jesus' ministry  after 2,000 years?**

Not expecting an answer immediately from any one denomination, but I would be more than curious to know if any Christian denomination(s) have started to make plans to celebrate Christ's three years of public ministry. It matters not to me in which way or manner they are doing any festivities. I am more interested to see if is this being brought forth by the various Christian communities, like Lent prepares us for Easter so to speak.

> Using astronomical data, Humphreys and Waddington have calculated that there are only two dates during this decade that a Friday Passover could be celebrated on Nissan 14—either April 7, AD 30 or April 3, AD 33.  - [Death of Jesus](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/%7Egrout/encyclopaedia_romana/calendar/jesus.html#:%7E:text=Jesus%20died%2C%20therefore%2C%20on%20Friday,in%20use%20at%20the%20time.)

Most scholars believe for different reasons, that Jesus died in the spring of either 30 AD or 33 AD. Astronomy narrows the possibilities to 27 AD, 30 AD, 33 AD or 34 AD.

[How long was Jesus's ministry?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14763/how-long-was-jesuss-ministry) It was 3.5 years of duration.

Taking this into consideration in my question, if any Church group were to accept the 27 AD possibility, what would they do in order to commemorate Jesus' three year public ministry prior to the 2000 anniversary of Passion, Death and Resurrection: 2024-2027.

I realized this question is posed early, but I would like to be able to commemorate Christ's three years of public ministry in some way or other in spirit and truth!

Any input would be greatly appreciated as to what preparations are being done in this domain. Any input from any denomination would be welcome.

Walking in the footprints of the Master!

Comment: Maybe the celebration will be that He comes back for us!  Good question.

Comment: Since there is so much uncertainty about dates, they may be content with the annual celebrations.

Comment: @StephenDisraeli Surely some will do things outside the box.

Comment: If nobody made a big thing of the 2000th anniversary of his birth I'm fairly sure they won't of his ministry.

Comment: @DJClayworth I beg to differ with you. If Pope St. John Paul ii wanted to prepare for the Great Jubilee of Christ's birth when he wrote [***Tertio Millennio Adveniente***](http://www.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/en/apost_letters/1994/documents/hf_jp-ii_apl_19941110_tertio-millennio-adveniente.html) in 1994 which invoked a three year plan of preparing for Christmas of 2000!

Comment: 1983 was declared a holy year by Pope JP2 as the 1950th anniversary of the Death and Resurrection of Our Lord.. It seems very possible that 2033 will be similarly marked, althoug of course more so since 2,000 is a rounder number so to speak. I cant say why 33Ad was chosen but 1983 implies it was. I do hope something is done to mark the whole 3.5 years.

Comment: Don't forget those that say it was [Wed.  25 April AD 31](http://intercontinentalcog.org/Appendix/Passover_dates_26-34_AD.php).

Comment: Given how many people celebrated the beginning of the 21st century a year early, and how few celebrated it on the correct date (one of the few predictions that Arthur C. Clarke was certain would come true), and that the correct date was known with 100% certainty, what are the chances that people or organizations will agree on a date for this event?

Comment: "It was 3.5 years of duration." YMMV.